# Can I use Android Studio's 'Find Useage' for Android SDK Source Code?

Tags: android, android-studio, grep

One of the most useful functions in AS is right-click and 'Find Useage' or 'See Declaration'. For my code, the 'Find Useage' will show all instances of where a function/object is used.

I have the SDK source code in AS too, but I can't 'Find Useage' on that code. Is there a way to set up my projects so that I can use 'Find Useage' on Android SDK code? For example, I would like to go to android/platform /frameworks/.../Configuration.java, right click on Configuration, and see where that class is being used elsewhere.

Failing that, is there a way to find useages short of grepping around the massive SDK project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. You can configure the scope of the search function.

Move the cursor on the symbol you want to analyse, press `Ctrl+Shift+a` (search for action) and search for `Find Usage Setting` or from the menu select `Edit -> Find -> Find Usage Setting` and select `Project and Libraries` in the scope section.

If the menu item is grayed out, it's because no symbol has been selected.

[image: Intellij Find Usage Dialog]

Furthermore, if you are looking for a particular feature in AS the search for action function is a huge time saver.

BTW: If `Project and Libraries` is not available it's because there is no usage of the selected symbol in any library.

Comment: Want to confirm on 'Ctrl+A' - that's just select-all for me

Comment: You are totally right. It's `Ctrl+Shift+a`, post corrected.

Answer (score 1):

May be you are looking for this:
Edit->Find->Find in path...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Android Platforms Codebase directly from the [repo](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base), then you can do it. In this case, you will have to update your dependencies by creating another gradle project in your studio where the platform codebase is and then import that in your project.

[image: Put the android_platforms_codebase in the sdk folder and check SO on how you can setup a multip-project build]